# c# creating a instance object of something

Tags: c#, json, anonymous-class

Hi I was wondering if something like this was possible or not, I'm sure my title question wasn't clear.

Say I have a function that returns a JSON representation of an object. Note: This is more pseudocode than anything don't correct me on the function.

```
public static json function(object){

}
```

Is it possible to define an object like this (I'm working with c#)

```
var exampleObject = { Name: "x" , PhoneNum: "123456789" }
```

I was hoping there would be a way to create a object with object attributes just like that on the fly without having to make a class like:

```
class exampleObject{
string name;
string phoneNum;
}
```

Does something like this exist? Thanks.

Comment: What you're asking for breaks the strong statically-typed nature of C#. If you *really* want to do this, you can [de-serialize the JSON into a `dynamic` object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object). However, it's much better to use either a `Dictionary`, or your own strongly-typed class which is much safer. See [How to decode a JSON string using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699972/how-to-decode-a-json-string-using-c?lq=1)

Comment: You were close. Check out documentation on anonymous types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  These are called anonymous types (although format and usage is a little different than what you have there).  You can find much more about anonymous types in C# on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx.

An example usage using info from your question would be:

```
var exampleObject = new { Name = "x", PhoneNum = "123456789" };
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)

```
dynamic exampleObject = new ExpandoObject();      
exampleObject.Name= "X";
exampleObject.PhoneNum= "123456789";
```