# How to Convert PHP to .NET For Beginners

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, .net

What options do I have for converting PHP to C#/ASP.NET?

I had a really tough time finding information on this, so I've created this question/answer to be a one stop shop for those of you who have also hit this kind of stumbling block.

In short, I will explain the different tools I'd found, what worked out for me, and also link you to some conversion guides.

Comment: This might be best as community wiki then

Comment: Apologies for not meeting community expectations and garnering downvotes.  I truly thought this was a beneficial topic to discuss based on the extreme difficulty I'd had trying to find a quick solution to this problem.  I have reworded the question section.  I hope that it will better assist those who are looking for these solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Microsoft's PHP to ASP.NET Migration Assistant**
http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/php-to-aspnet
The Good:
Microsoft has a PHP to ASP.NET Migration Assistant!  It's not perfect, but does fairly well despite the differences inherent in the languages.  It doesn't create the codebehind for you, but rather, puts generated C# in a script tag in an .aspx file.

The Bad:
It was a challenge getting this working because it's a little old and required me to install [Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Redist](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/a/c/aac39226-8825-44ce-90e3-bf8203e74006/dotnetfx.exe), and [Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 Service Pack 1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/b/4/8b4addd8-e957-4dea-bdb8-c4e00af5b94b/NDP1.1sp1-KB867460-X86.exe) in VS2010 in order to install the Migration Assistant itself.

Some of you may have trouble with these Framework installations.  If you do, I found a handy dandy guide right here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-install-net-framework-11-in-windows-7-64/eb1e6232-e874-432e-ab43-17660e25e43d?page=1&tm=1345067625733

Also, after I'd gotten it to install, it wasn't appearing in my conversion tools in VS2010.  So, I had to do this:
[http://forums.asp.net/t/1530808.aspx?no+PHP+to+ASP+NET+Migration+Assistant+in+MS+Visual+Studio+2008](http://forums.asp.net/t/1530808.aspx?no%20PHP%20to%20ASP%20NET%20Migration%20Assistant%20in%20MS%20Visual%20Studio%202008)

> Re: no PHP to ASP.NET Migration Assistant in MS Visual Studio 2008
>   Apr 11, 2012 10:15 PM|LINK
>
> Once you install the Migration assistant open a DOS window thru
>   CMD.exe In the dos window : Change directory to:     CD C:\Documents
>   and Settings\spatel>cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Corporation\PHP t o
>   ASP.NET Migration Assistant Then type in the following and click enter
>   : PHPCONVERT.EXE  C:\PhpSourceDirectory  /Out C:\ASPoutputdirectory
>   Open the project from within Visual Studio 2008 and choolse to
>   convert.  Note: in the step 3 above C:\PhpSourceDirectory  is where I
>   had my PHP files stored and similarly C:\ASPoutputdirectory is where I
>   wanted my ASP.net output to go.
>
> PHPCONVERT.EXE  has other options that you can explore by typing in
>   PHPCONVERT.EXE  /?
>
> When I saw this forum ...I gave hope but PHPCONVERT.EXE was a life
>   saver , my work effort reduced by 90% for the conversion.
>
> The latest version of the convertor is available @
>   http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/php-to-aspnet

I'll note that these command lines needed tweaking for an x86 machine.  PHPCONVERT.EXE might be in Program Files(x86) instead of Program Files.

Overall, it took some time, but that's what I had to do to get it working, I hope that this helps you out of your current bind.

**Phalanger - A PHP Compiler for Visual Studio**

If you want PHP to compile in your .NET app try Phalanger 
[http://www.php-compiler.net/](http://www.php-compiler.net)

I was interested in this, but ultimately decided against it due to licence fees.  However, they are on GitHub if you want to check it out.
https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger

**Converting PHP Yourself**
Here are some resources for learning PHP basics, and a bare-bones conversion guide.
http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/php/
http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20100603-0518

Thanks everyone!  All the best to you, and happy coding.

Comment: Does this still work?