# Parsing nested json with n number of json objects in c#

Tags: c#, json, api, model-view-controller, deserialization

i am a newbie to coding , I have a nested json coming from a external source the json format is looks something like this ..

```
{
 "data":"data",
 "data":
       {
         "data":"data",
           //----------------e.t.c the internal objects could be in n number
       }
}
```

so how do i deserialize the json object and use the data as a list in order to do my other operations like sql and posting the data??

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)
and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699972/how-to-decode-a-json-string-using-c/7701070#7701070) SO question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a class that is appropriate with the Json, like that:

```
public someClass
{
    public string data1 { get; set; }
    public DataClass dataArr { get; set; }
}

public DataClass
{
    public string insideData { get; set; }
}
```

after you do this you need the following code:

```
var jsonDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<someClass>(yourJson);
```

Comment: so for this solution the inside data can be { "x" : "x" , "y":"y" ....... ,} am i right???

Comment: @SaiChaitanya i didn't understand...what do you mean please?

Comment: I mean to say the internal data ,i.e. the nested json can be  {"data1:data1,........,n different data} correct ?